# Problems with SQL exercise from sql-ex

Tags: sql

I have a database "Painting", it consists of 3 tables:

- utQ (Q_ID int, Q_NAME varchar(35))
- utV (V_ID int, V_NAME varchar(35), V_COLOR char(1))
- utB (B_Q_ID int, B_V_ID int, B_VOL tinyint, B_DATETIME datetime).

The utQ table contains the identifiers and names of squares, the initial color of which is black. (Note: black is not a color and is considered unpainted. Only Red, Green and Blue are colors.) 
The utV table contains the identifiers and names of spray cans and the color of paint they are filled with.
The utB table holds information on squares being spray-painted, and contains the square and spray can identifiers, the quantity of paint being applied, and the time of the painting event.

It should be noted that

- a spray can may contain paint of one of three colors: red (V_COLOR='R'), green (V_COLOR='G'), or blue (V_COLOR='B');

  - any spray can initially contains 255 units of paint;
  - the square color is defined in accordance with the RGB model, i.e. R=0, G=0, B=0 is black, whereas R=255, G=255, B=255 is white;
  - any record in the utB table decreases the paint quantity in the corresponding spray can by B_VOL and accordingly increases the amount of paint applied to the square by the same value;
  - B_VOL must be greater than 0 and less or equal to 255;
  - the paint quantity of a single color applied to one square can’t exceed 255, and there can’t be a less than zero amount of paint in a spray can;
  - the time of the painting event (B_DATETIME) is specified with one second precision, i.e. it does not contain milliseconds;
  - for historical reasons, the spray cans are referred to as “balloons” by many of the exercises, and the utV table contains spray can names (V_NAME column) such as “Balloon # 01”, etc

This is the schema

[image]

And the question is

> What the maximal number of black squares could be painted white color with paint remainder?

My solution looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SUM(t.rest) / 255 tot_rest FROM

   (SELECT V_ID, 
            V_COLOR, 
             COALESCE(255-SUM(B_VOL), 255) rest 
   FROM utV LEFT JOIN utB ON utV.V_ID = utB.B_V_ID 
   GROUP BY V_ID, V_COLOR 
   HAVING COALESCE(255-SUM(B_VOL), 255) != 0) t 

GROUP BY t.v_color 
ORDER BY SUM(t.rest) / 255
```

Unfortunately it doesn't pass all tests. Could you please help me, what I've done wrong? (All "solutions" to this exercise, which I've found, also don't pass all tests)

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my query didn't consider the case when at least one color is absent in database. For example, if there are no records in utV and utB with red spray cans the right query should return 0, however my query returns some number.

The correct query is:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 3 then MIN(t1.tot_rest) ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        (SELECT SUM(t.rest) / 255 tot_rest FROM
             (SELECT V_ID, 
                V_COLOR, 
                 COALESCE(255-SUM(B_VOL), 255) rest 
       FROM utV LEFT JOIN utB ON utV.V_ID = utB.B_V_ID 
       GROUP BY V_ID, V_COLOR) t 

    GROUP BY t.v_color) t1
```